# Date range Query in kibana 5.6.3 not working with @timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

**mapping:**

```
  "mappings": {
                "test-engine": {
                  "properties": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                      "type": "date"
                    } ....
             },
```

**sample record:**

```
     {
    "_index": "application-log",
    "_type": "test-engine",
    "_id": "AV9pKiMHlm36MlYWarx3",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "@timestamp": "2017-10-29T17:24:50.026+0000",
      "message": "Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request",
      "host": "54.205.134.57",
      "severity": "DEBUG",
      "thread": "Thread-4",
      "logger": "org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient"
    }
```

**the query which I have tried:**

```
     GET application-log/_mapping
     {
      "range": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "gte": "2017-10-26T17:24:50.026+0000",
          "lte": "2017-10-28T17:24:50.026+0000"
        }
      }
    }
```

I tried the query with above mappings and records still the date range is not working in kibana

Comment: You just need to wrap your `range` query in the `query` section, i.e. `{"query":{ "range": ...}}`

Comment: @Val thanks, val I tried your suggestion  {
  "query": 
   {          "range": {            "@timestamp": {  "gte": "2017-10-31T08:00:11.210+0000",
              "lte": "2017-10-31T08:00:11.210+0000"
            } } }}  even this is not working

Comment: Make sure to remove the blank line between GET and the query and use the `_search` endpoint, not the `_mapping` one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `_search` endpoint no the `_mapping` one and wrap the `range` query inside a `query` section

```
 GET application-log/_search
 {
   "query": {
     "range": {
       "@timestamp": {
         "gte": "2017-10-26T17:24:50.026+0000",
         "lte": "2017-10-28T17:24:50.026+0000"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```